# Run-Time Check Failure #3 - T

Tags: c++

Ошибка при отладке в Visual Studio 2015.
Если вводить значение больше единицы то программа работает, вводишь меньше - ломается.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int y=0, eps, i=2, s;
    cout << "Enter eps " << "\n";
    cin >> eps;
    if (eps >= 1) {
        cout << "Error" << "\n";
    }
    else {
        while (eps > s) {
            s = 1 / i;
            i++;
            y = y + s;
        }
        cout << "y=" << y;
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Если бы Вы действительно занялись отладкой, Вы бы локализовали проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Целочисленное деление  `s = 1 / i;` при ваших `i>=2` всегда дает 0. Работайте с переменными `double`, например, а вместо `1` пишите `1.0`.